# How to Select Data in Between Timestamps Separated by a 30 Second Interval

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good day. I have two tables, `TableA` and `TableB`. `TableA` has a start and stop time. `TableB` has data with timestamps. I am trying to separate `TableA` into a larger table separated by 30 second intervals and have `TableBs` data join to the nearest 30 second timestamp between the start and stop time.

How do I efficiently create a table separated by 30 second intervals and join another tables data based on the nearest time stamp? Any help is much appreciated.

TableA

```
pkid     dateEntered
    1       2018-10-09 14:18:34.823
    2       2018-10-09 14:28:30.963
```

TableB

```
processVal  dateEntered
55.2431   2018-10-09 14:18:34.953
55.2158   2018-10-09 14:19:04.960
54.7972   2018-10-09 14:19:34.963
54.7933   2018-10-09 14:20:04.963
54.7661   2018-10-09 14:20:34.967
54.7427   2018-10-09 14:21:04.967
54.7193   2018-10-09 14:21:34.970
54.6921   2018-10-09 14:22:04.970
54.6668   2018-10-09 14:22:34.973
54.6375   2018-10-09 14:23:04.973
54.6142   2018-10-09 14:23:34.977
54.585    2018-10-09 14:24:04.977
54.5597   2018-10-09 14:24:34.980
54.5363   2018-10-09 14:25:04.980
54.509    2018-10-09 14:25:34.983
54.4857   2018-10-09 14:26:04.987
54.4584   2018-10-09 14:26:34.987
54.435    2018-10-09 14:27:04.987
54.4097   2018-10-09 14:27:34.990
54.3825   2018-10-09 14:28:04.990
```

Desired Results

```
55.2431   2018-10-09 14:18:30.000
55.2158   2018-10-09 14:19:00.000
54.7972   2018-10-09 14:19:30.000
54.7933   2018-10-09 14:20:00.000
54.7661   2018-10-09 14:20:30.000
54.7427   2018-10-09 14:21:00.000
54.7193   2018-10-09 14:21:30.000
54.6921   2018-10-09 14:22:00.000
54.6668   2018-10-09 14:22:30.000
54.6375   2018-10-09 14:23:00.000
54.6142   2018-10-09 14:23:30.000
54.585    2018-10-09 14:24:00.000
54.5597   2018-10-09 14:24:30.000
54.5363   2018-10-09 14:25:00.000
54.509    2018-10-09 14:25:30.000
54.4857   2018-10-09 14:26:00.000
54.4584   2018-10-09 14:26:30.000
54.435    2018-10-09 14:27:00.000
54.4097   2018-10-09 14:27:30.000
54.3825   2018-10-09 14:28:00.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try following SQL Select with CASE statement and DATEADD() function

```
declare @startdate datetime = '2018-10-09 14:18:34.823'
declare @enddate datetime = '2018-10-09 14:28:30.963'

select 
    case when DATEPART(ss, DateEntered) < 30 
    then 
        dateadd(ms,-1 * (DATEPART(ms, DateEntered) ), dateadd(ss,-1 * (DATEPART(ss, DateEntered) ),DateEntered))
    else 
        dateadd(ms,-1 * (DATEPART(ms, DateEntered) ), dateadd(ss,60 -1 * (DATEPART(ss, DateEntered) ),DateEntered)) 
    end
from TableB
where
DateEntered between @startdate and @enddate
```

Comment: If one wanted that 30 seconds to be a dynamic parameter, would it be replacing the 30 with the variable? I tried doing that but it seems like its only parsing up to every minute but doesnt do every 120 seconds for example.

Comment: The code decides rounding by checking only the seconds parts of the time value. So if you need rounding between 2 minutes, you need to check the last digit of the minute. If it is even, then round to lower, if it is odd round to upper bound. I can also prepare its code, but to make it dynamic requires more control